# Remover tuplas de uma lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gostaria de saber como faço para remover uma tupla de uma lista, caso o primeiro índice desta tupla se repete dentre os elementos da lista. Ex:

Se eu tiver uma lista de tuplas com os valores, [('joao', 23), ('joao', 24)], deixar apenas a primeira tupla com o valor joao. Meu código está assim até o momento, qualquer alteração, edito aqui também.

```
nomes = []
idades = []


while True:
    nome = input('Insira um nome: ')
    if nome == 's':
        break
    idade = int(input('Insira sua idade: '))
    nomes.append(nome)
    idades.append(idade)

pessoas = list(zip(nomes, idades))
print(pessoas)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lista = [('joao', 13),('joao', 23), ('joao', 24),('maria', 23), ('joao', 22), ('maria', 24), ('joaquina', 33)]
```

Pode transformar em dicionário, assim irá remover as chaves que são iguais. Passo a lista reversa pois você quer o  primeiro elemento.

```
[*{k:v for k,v in lista[::-1]}.items()]
```

Saída:

```
[('joaquina', 33), ('maria', 23), ('joao', 13)]
```

Comment: Não seria mais simples `print([*dict(lista[::-1]).items()])`

Comment: @AugustoVasques, opa seria sim mas fiz pra praticar o dict comprehension kkkk. Grande abraço!!

Answer (score 0):

Uma das soluções que poderia ser implementada é uma função para remover os nomes duplicados, deixando somente o primeiro a ser encontrado:

```
def remover_nomes_duplicados(lista):
    nomes = []
    idades = []
    for pessoa in lista:
        if pessoa[0] not in nomes:
            nomes.append(pessoa[0])
            idades.append(pessoa[1])
    return list(zip(nomes, idades))
```

Portanto, seu código ficaria desta maneira:

```
def remover_nomes_duplicados(lista):
    nomes = []
    idades = []
    for pessoa in lista:
        if pessoa[0] not in nomes:
            nomes.append(pessoa[0])
            idades.append(pessoa[1])
    return list(zip(nomes, idades))


nomes = []
idades = []

while True:
    nome = input('Insira um nome: ')
    if nome == 's':
        break
    idade = int(input('Insira sua idade: '))
    nomes.append(nome)
    idades.append(idade)

print(remover_nomes_duplicados(list(zip(nomes, idades))))
```

Neste código existem várias redundâncias e erros convencionais, mas como é somente um exemplo, tentei seguir o mesmo modo que você fez para melhor entendimento. Contudo, encorajo a leitura do PEP 8.